# multiple dropdowns, disable second dropdown if first option in first dropdown is selected

Tags: jquery, select

I have a list of cople dropdown selects. what I need is to disable second dropdown if first option in first dropdown is selected. A jQuery answer will be much appreciated.

```html
<select name='cat1'>
    <option value='0'>Select one</option>
    <option value='1'>little</option>
    <option value='2'>good</option>
</select>
        
<select name='soft1'>
     <option value=''>Select one</option>
     <option value='W'>Word</option>
     <option value='E'>Excel</option>
     <option value='PP'>Power Point</option>
 </select>

<br />

<select name='cat2'>
    <option value='0'>Select one</option>
    <option value='1'>little</option>
    <option value='2'>good</option>
</select>
        
<select name='soft2'>
    <option value=''>Select one</option>
    <option value='W'>Word</option>
    <option value='E'>Excel</option>
    <option value='PP'>Power Point</option>
</select>

<br />
<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').delegate("select[name^='cat']","change",function(){
 if($(this).val() == 0){ //first option
    $('select').prop( "disabled", false); //enable all select box
     //disable the very next one
      $(this).next().prop( "disabled", true );
       }
   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `selectedIndex`

```js
var setEnabled = function(e) {
  var name = this.name.replace(/1/, '2'); //get name for second drop down
  $('select[name=' + name + ']')
      .prop('disabled', 0 === this.selectedIndex) // disable if selected option is first one
};

$(function() {
  $('select[name=cat1], select[name=soft1]')
      .on('change', setEnabled)
      .trigger('change'); // trigger on page load
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name='cat1'>
  <option value='0'>Select one</option>
  <option value='1'>little</option>
  <option value='2'>good</option>
</select>

<select name='soft1'>
  <option value=''>Select one</option>
  <option value='W'>Word</option>
  <option value='E'>Excel</option>
  <option value='PP'>Power Point</option>
</select>

<br />

<select name='cat2'>
  <option value='0'>Select one</option>
  <option value='1'>little</option>
  <option value='2'>good</option>
</select>

<select name='soft2'>
  <option value=''>Select one</option>
  <option value='W'>Word</option>
  <option value='E'>Excel</option>
  <option value='PP'>Power Point</option>
</select>
```